# Will Mahoraga able to adapt to the hit by the Inverted Spear of Heaven?

Tags: jujutsu-kaisen

I saw the scene of Gojo vs Toji once again on YouTube and it got me thinking about the weapon used by Toji. The Inverted Spear of Heaven nullifies the Cursed Technique and can bypass the limitless. Since Mahoraga can "*adapt to any and all phenomena*", will it be able to adapt to the hit by the Inverted Spear of Heaven?

I searched online and found out that I am not the only one with this question. I am getting mixed answers in all of them so I am posting it here. I am an anime-only person but if the answer is from the Manga, I am okay with it.

[image: weapon-image]